# Column wrappring in Bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have 3 columns with content. On small screens, I want the columns to be displayed under each other. So far, so good.

On large screens, I want column 1 and column 2 to be displayed beside of each other, and column 3 to be displayed under column 1. It works, but if the content in column 2 is big, I get much space between column 1 and column 3. See attached screenshots.

How can I fix this, so that the column 3 is displayed directly under column 1 on large screens? Even if the content in column 2 is more / bigger that the content in column 1.

**Large screens:**

[image]

**Small screens**

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Column 1</p>
    <p>
      Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Column 2</p>
    <p>
      Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2
      Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2
      Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2
      Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <p>Column 3</p>
    <p>
      Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: need more clarification, what you really want to do?

Comment: I want column 1, column 2 and column 3 to be displayed under each other on small screens. On large screens, I want Column 1 and Column 3 to be displayed under each other to the left, and columt 2 to be displayed to the right.

Comment: This is how HTML works. There are libraries (JS) that could help you achieve what you are after such as http://macyjs.com/ or https://masonry.desandro.com/ or https://muuri.dev/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution that fixed the varying column heights problem. It's a plugin called Masonry. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space. See masonry.desandro.com.